# JQuery on mouseover with MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

i have a table that shows a surgery availability for a week. I'v been looking into a JQuery mouseover to show a pop up when the user hovers over the row id. I need it to print the row depending on the id. To make this more clear have a look at this screenshot first:

[image]

You see on the screenshot on Wed at 10AM Moe has an appointment with id 4. When the user hovers over 4 a popup should be displayed with the rows associated with that id. so for 4 it will be:
PatientId - 1934, apptDate - 2015-12-02, surname - Aqeel, doctorName - Moe, altamORpm - Y, altdate - Y, altdoctor - Y, booked - Y.

How would i go about starting this? i have never used JQuery before so please bear with me. Any help will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'DoctorAvailability';
include ('header.html');

echo '<h3>Doctor Availability</h3>';

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM booking";
$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($results) {
    if ($numrows >0) {
        echo '<p>There are ' . $numrows . ' patience(s)</p>';
        echo '<table>
        <tr> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Patient ID</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Surname</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>AM or PM</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Date Requested</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Time Requested</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Doctor</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Alternative AM or PM</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Alternative Date</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Alternative Doctor</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Date</stong></font></td> <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Booked</stong></font></td> </tr>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff">' . $row['id'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['surname'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['amORpm'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['apptDate'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['apptTime'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['doctorName'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['altamORpm'] . '</font></td>  <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['altdate'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">' . $row['altdoctor'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">'. $row['date'] . '</font></td> <td bgcolor="#9f9f9f"><font color="#fff">'. $row['booked'] . '</font></td> </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'; 

        mysqli_free_result ($results);  
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">There are no patiences.</p>';
    }
} else { 

echo '<h3 class="error">System Error</h3>
    <p class="error">User data could not be retrieved.</p>';
} 

$query = "select ts.theTime,d.doctorName, 
bMon.id as bMon, bTue.id as bTue, bWed.id as bWed, bThu.id as bThu, bFri.id as bFri 
from timeSlots ts 
cross join doctors d 
left join booking bMon 
on bMon.apptDate=@Monday and bMon.timeSlotId=ts.id and bMon.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bTue 
on bTue.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and bTue.timeSlotId=ts.id and bTue.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bWed 
on bWed.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 2 DAY) and bWed.timeSlotId=ts.id and bWed.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bThu 
on bThu.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 3 DAY) and bThu.timeSlotId=ts.id and bThu.doctorId=d.doctorId 
left join booking bFri 
on bFri.apptDate=date_add(@Monday, INTERVAL 4 DAY) and bFri.timeSlotId=ts.id and bFri.doctorId=d.doctorId 
cross join (select @Monday:='2015-11-30') params 
order by ts.theTime,d.doctorName;";

$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
//$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($results) {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>The Time</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Doctor Name</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Monday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Tuesday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Wednesday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Thursday</stong></font></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><strong>Friday</stong></font></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#DC0E03"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['theTime']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="#BABABA"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['doctorName']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bMon'])){ echo '#179741'; }else{ echo '#cc362e'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bMon']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bTue'])){ echo '#179741'; }else{ echo '#cc362e'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bTue']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bWed'])){ echo '#179741'; }else{ echo '#cc362e'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bWed']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bThu'])){ echo '#179741'; }else{ echo '#cc362e'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bThu']; ?></font></td> 
                <td bgcolor="<?php if(empty($row['bFri'])){ echo '#179741'; }else{ echo '#cc362e'; } ?>"><font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bFri']; ?></font></td>
                <td><a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello World!</span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    mysqli_free_result ($results);  
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">There are no patients.</p>';
}

mysqli_close($conn); 

?> 

<?php
echo '<a href="update.php?\n">Click: --> Update Patient Personal Details <--</a>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple tooltip like this:

```css
a span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a {position: relative;}
a:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a>
```

This is just one of a pure CSS solution.

---

**Updated Code**

Can you please change all of these:

```
<font color="#fff"><?php echo $row['bTue']; ?></font>
```

with something similar to this:

```
<font color="#fff">
  <a class="popup">
    <?php echo $row['bFri']; ?>
    <span><?php // Put whatever you want in this. ?></span>
  </a>
</font>
```

And give this CSS:

```css
a.popup span {display: none; position: absolute; color: #fff; background: #000; padding: 5px;}
a.popup {position: relative;}
a.popup:hover span {display: block; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Is there a way to connect this to my database and print rows when mouse hover over? @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Tuks Yes. Write the markup that way, giving the number instead of `Hover Me!` and whatever you want it to display, instead of `Hello, World!`.

Comment: i am trying to look at it now, i do not get it, how would i query the database to bring back the results i wish to display in the little popup? This is my code here: http://pastie.org/10614036

Comment: i have edited comment above with code.. as you can see i am echo out bMon, bTue etc from the database which are colour coded, red if unavailable, green if available. how would i create a hover so it is attached to the id number that is printed in these cells bMon, bTue etc which will essentially bring back surname, patientId etc

Comment: the updated answer you just edited is the same as what i already had? :/ @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Tuks sorry buddy... Just replace the above and add the CSS at the end... It should work..

Comment: the pop up now there whenever i hover over the id number but it is saying unidentified index for surname, this is how i did it:

    <a class="popup"><?php echo $row['bMon']; ?><span><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></span></a></font>

Comment: Sorry i am very new to all this so please bear with me @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Tuks Do you have a `surname` field in your database?

Comment: yes surname is in my database, is it because surname is not included in my query? the doctorName is included in my query when i changed surname to doctorName the popup works fine and brings back the doctorName.

Comment: @Tuks Yea, you have to include it in your query.

Comment: Your answer is great, i have given a tick mark, is there any chance you can point me in the right direction to get this unidentified index resolved? Thank you for all the help you have given so far :) @PraveenKumar

Comment: is it possible to have 2 queries or would i need to incorporate it in the one i have?

Comment: @Tuks Better to have it in the same query please?

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML and PHP markup I only can guess some solutions:

**First -** When you get  your data you can embed it in the HTML so you can use the option proposed by @Praveen.

**Second -** You could use jquery ajax call to get your data when the user will hover the 4 and show accordingly the returned data.

Once again You need to post here your HTML and PHP code If you expect to get some help. Your screenshot looks nice but doesn't give us any information about the way you are gathering your data.